# Order of Evaluation in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am confused regarding the order of evaluation in javascript. For ex, this is the code I have written

```
this.getTabUrl=function()
{
    this.logToConsole("1"+"getTabUrl is called");

    var myUrl
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
    {
        myUrl = tab.url;
        console.log("2"+tab.url);
        console.log("3"+myUrl);
        //this.parent.logToConsole(tabUrl);

    });

    this.tabUrl=myUrl;

    this.logToConsole("3.1"+myUrl);
    this.logToConsole("4"+this.tabUrl);

    return myUrl;

}
```

When I call this function, this is the Output I get

```
> 1getTabUrl is called
> 3.1undefined 
> 4undefined 
> 2undefined
```

How come 3.1 and 4 is evaluated first before 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function passed to `chrome.tabs.getSelected()` is executed asynchronously.

You need to put everything that needs whatever gets passed to the callback inside the callback function. Note that this means you cannot `return` a value from the outer function that relies on something from the callback. You need to accept a callback argument instead and call it with the return value.

Comment: Thanks. That help.s I simply want to return the Url from, getTabUrl function, can you tell me how to do it